# Blackjack if statement

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, blackjack

I am making a simple black jack game and I am having problems with my if 
statement. When I click the stand button which triggers the if statement it always displays the prompt "you win" not no matter what the score is.

For example if the user score if 11 and the computer score is 18(which it is always set to) the prompt "you lose" should be displayed.

```js
     
 var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);

 function random() {
     return randomnumber;
 }

 var total = randomnumber;

 function dealcard() {
     total += Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
     document.getElementById('playerscards').value = total;

     if (total > 21) {
         alert("You have gone bust click new game to play again!");
     }
 }

 function keepcards() 
 {
     if (total > randomnumber) {
         alert("You win!");
     }    
     else if (total < randomnumber) {
         alert("You lose!");
     }    
     else if (total === randomnumber) {
         alert("It is a draw!");}     
     }
 now = new Date();
 localtime = now.toString();  
 hours = now.getHours();
 mins = now.getMinutes();
 secs = now.getSeconds();
 document.write("<h1>");
 document.write(hours + ":" + mins + ":" + secs);
 document.write("</h1>");
```

```html
<head>
    <h1><i>BLACKJACK</i></h1>
    <h4>
    Computers Cards: <input type="text" id="computerscards" value="18">
    <br>Player 1 cards: <input type="text" id="playerscards">
    </h4>
</head>

<input type="button" value="start" 
    onclick="document.getElementById('playerscards').value = random()">

<input type="button" value="deal" onclick="dealcard()">
<input type="button" value="stand" onclick="keepcards()">
<input type="button" value="new game" onclick="window.location.reload()">

<p>To start the game press start and draw a card<br> Press deal to add a new 
card <br> press stand if you do not wish to draw a new card<br> Press new game 
if you want to refresh the page to play a mew game</p>
```

Comment: line9: ` var total = randomnumber;` after that I think you click on: `deal` what increment the value of `total`:  `total += Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);`  in `keepcards()` you have this: ` if (total > randomnumber)` what is true.

Answer (score 0):

If you debug your code you'll see that you are checking the total value against the randomNumber, but to really check if the player won, is necessary to check it against the ComputerHand right?
 So I did it below in the snippet.
Right now you code fix the coumputerHand to 18, in a near future i assume that you'll change that in a way that computer receives a ramdom card like the player.

```js
var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);

    function random() {
      return randomnumber;
    }

    var total = randomnumber;
    var CPUHand = parseInt(document.getElementById('computerscards').value);

    function dealcard() {
      total += Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
      document.getElementById('playerscards').value = total;

      if (total > 21) {
        alert("You have gone bust click new game to play again!");
      }
    }

    function keepcards(){
      debugger;

      if (total > CPUHand) {
        alert("You win!");
      }    
      else if (total < CPUHand) {
        alert("You lose!");
      }    
      else if (total === CPUHand) {
        alert("It is a draw!");
      }     
    }
    
      now = new Date();
      localtime = now.toString();  
      hours = now.getHours();
      mins = now.getMinutes();
      secs = now.getSeconds();
      document.write("<h1>");
      document.write(hours + ":" + mins + ":" + secs);
      document.write("</h1>");
```

```html
<head>
    <h1><i>BLACKJACK</i></h1>
    <h4>
    Computers Cards: <input type="text" id="computerscards" value="18">
    <br>Player 1 cards: <input type="text" id="playerscards">
    </h4>
    </head>

    <input type="button" value="start" 
    onclick="document.getElementById('playerscards').value = random()">

    <input type="button" value="deal" onclick="dealcard()">

    <input type="button" value="stand" onclick="keepcards()">

    <input type="button" value="new game" onclick="window.location.reload()">

    <p>To start the game press start and draw a card<br> Press deal to add a new 
    card <br> press stand if you do not wish to draw a new card<br> Prsee new 
    game 
    if you want to refresh the page to play a mew game</p>
```

Comment: you're welcome. please upvote and mark as correct if this helped you :D